# Enabling Unicode Support in Solr

Tags: java, unicode, solr

I want to enable the Unicode in Solr. Updating the index does not give me an error. 
But as soon as I try to search some Chinese text, I get an error. I have added the following line to my schema.

```
<filter class="solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory" language="" strength="primary"/>
```

and now I am getting following exception.

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory'
>    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:375)
>   at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.newInstance(SolrResourceLoader.java:390)
>   at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.create(AbstractPluginLoader.java:84)
>   at org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:141)
>   at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:835)

Comment: what version of Solr are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UnicodeCollation), CollationKeyFilterFactory is currently only available in trunk. That's why you get an error that the class doesn't exist.